# Parse a datetime string that has no 'T' separator using java.time

Tags: datetime-format, java-time, iso, localtime

I am trying to parse string "2023-05-10 09:41:00" to LocalTime using java.time library.

When I try `LocalTime.parse("2023-05-10 09:41:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)` I get `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`. However when I try `LocalTime.parse("2023-05-10T09:41:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)` it works.

Is there any `DateTimeFormatter` constant I can use that works without the "T" separator? I am aware I can use a custom DateTimeFormatter but I would like to use a prepackaged constant from java or kotlin library like pseudo code `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME_WIHOUT_T`.

Comment: The hack is to insert the `T` yourself: `"2023-05-10 09:41:00".replace(' ', 'T')`. This will allow you to use the existing formatter constant. The solution is to construct your own formatter for parsing, for example `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`.

Comment: But I agree that it is better to use the built-in formatters. We can. It gets a bit wordier, but personally I find it worth it: `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder() .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE) .appendLiteral(' ') .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME) .toFormatter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any `DateTimeFormatter` constant I can use that works without
> the "T" separator?

There is none because `java.time` is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which uses a date-time string with `T` as the time separator.

However, you can achieve it with some hacks (just for fun, not for production code).

**Demo**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2023-05-10 09:41:00";
        ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(strDateTime.indexOf(' ') + 1);
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME.parse(strDateTime, position));
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
09:41
```

There is another hack which Ole V.V. has already mentioned in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76219805/parse-a-datetime-string-that-has-no-t-separator-using-java-time#comment134412613_76219805).

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/0fYLfx)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.